# scroll position changes when window is resized (in firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design, resize

I'm working on a responsive CSS snap-scrolling website and I'm encountering a problem in firefox when I'm adjusting the window size.
Adjusting the hight of the window messes up the scroll-position on the Y-Axis.
Changing the width does the same for the horizontal slides.

I've recreated the layout in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/000tin/full/VwmVPjX

```
<div class="main-header"><h1>header</h1></div>

    <div class="snap-section first-section red"><h1>section 1</h1></div>
    <div class="snap-section orange">
         <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <section class="orange"><h1>section 2a</h1></section>
            <section class="light-green"><h1>section 2b</h1></section>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="snap-section yellow"><h1>section 3</h1></div>
    <div class="snap-section light-green"><h1>section 4</h1></div>
    <div class="snap-section green"><h1>section 5</h1></div>
    <div class="snap-section blue final-section"><h1>section 6</h1></div>

    <div class="snap-section main-footer"><h1>footer</h1></div>
```

It's only happening in Firefox. Chrome and Safari hold on to the right position perfectly.
Has anyone dealt with this problem before or knows a solution?
I can't find anything on it.

Thanks x

Comment: I tried it with Firefox and it's working fine! I could't see any mistakes. Btw i'm impressed! That looks so nice

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 Really? Maybe it's a macOS + firefox situation then. It's kind of bothering me, but i guess it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 Thank you so much lol. Here is the finished skeleton http://000tin.bplaced.net/ It's going to feel very different when I insert all the content though.

Comment: Hahaha I am already curious! Have fun and good luck!

Comment: did you find a solution to this? you're codepen seems to work for me. but I'm having an issue with scroll-snap in firefox on macos, but it's fine in Chrome and safari when I resize the window.